# How to disable TRACE Http Method on ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, security, http

We have a asp.net mvc 3 application hosted in IIS 7.5. We need to disable the TRACE HTTP METHOD for security reason.

I googled a bit but could not find any concrete example on above. Could someone help, how this can be achieved either via IIS setting or via web.config.

Thanks.

Comment: `<system.web><trace enabled="false"/></system.web>`

Comment: This one doesn't work. I'm referring to Trace HTTP Method not asap.net trace

Comment: What do u mean by `Trace HTTP Method` ?

Answer (score 2):

From the `web.config`

```
<configuration>
 <system.webServer>
  <security>
   <requestFiltering>
    <verbs allowUnlisted="true">
     <add verb="TRACE" allowed="false" />
    </verbs>
   </requestFiltering>
  </security>
 </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/manage/configuring-security/use-request-filtering#filter-by-verbs